# I cannot get imagemagick to work in PHP on windows server 2016 that is not thread safe

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick, imagick

I cannot get Imagemagick to work in PHP on windows server 2016 that is not thread safe. When ever I call the 'Imagick' class name it says "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Imagick' not found".

Also when I run ImageMagick commands from the command line the following command does not work:

magick --version

The below does work though:

./magick --version

Answer (score 0):

imagick and imagemagick are two different things.

imagemagick is the CLI program. Imagick is a wrapper class in PHP that talks to the application.

You just need to install the IMagick class:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php

Comment: Which download has the class in it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so my issue was that I have a server which is x64 but have x86 version of PHP installed. I switched my imagick.dll from x64 to the x86 version and it works. Hope this weird scenario helps someone